# Are $111^*$ and $11^*1$ equivalent?

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I know it is a trivial question but are $111^*$ and $11^*1$ equivalent? (I think yes because I can have 11 in both at minimum but that seems odd to be true). I am trying to understand automata theory and I am currently converting an AFD -> AFN -> Regular expression. I perhaps made a mistake while converting but my AFD gives $11^*1$ (with other terms) and my AFN gives $111^*$ (with other terms). So I would like to know if they are the same or if I did a mistake while converting.

If they are not equivalent, how do we convert an AFN to AFD in this scenario and respecting that specific order? (see attached)

[image: part of the AFD here]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Are those read as $11(1^*)$ and $1(1^*)1$? If so, then yes; they both accept exactly the set of strings of $n\geq 2$ copies of $1$.

Comment: thanks for that ! @Shaun

Comment: Ok I see, yes I guess they are read like this. I was the one to derive the regular expression and I thought of it like that. Thanks for the answer! @anomaly

Comment: Is $1 + 1 + k = 1 + k + 1$?

Comment: Yes said like that, it is seems very trivial. I just wanted to make sure since I thought that in automata theory, order matters to a certain degree but since they are equivalent I guess it is okay or maybe I should have added more states to my AFD.

Comment: Order does matter in general, but since all '1's are the same, order is moot. I should have written $\{ 1 1 1^k \}_k = \{ 1 1^k 1 \}_k$. That is, the accepted languages are the same.